# Estimator pdf = likelihood function?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, density-function

In the context of a discussion of consistency of an estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$ (where n is the sample size), what is the meaning of its pdf? Is it the same as its likelihood function?

Comment: They are not the same and similar questions have been asked here previously.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Would you care to elaborate and/or point to similar questions?

Comment: Look when I search this site for questions regarding whether the likelihood equals the pdf there are 64 hits.